# htmx hx-vals js not executed

Tags: javascript, htmx

I struggle to get js to work in vals for a hx-get request.

My HTML is the following

```
<script>
    console.log("to start with")
    function getWidth() {
        console.log("here we are")
        return 1
    }
</script>
<div hx-get="/game_visuals" 
    hx-swap="innerHtml" 
    hx-trigger="load"
    hx-vals='js:{width: getWidth()}'>
</div>
```

I expect to see log entries

- to start with
- here we are

however I only see to start with and my get request is sent without parameters. If I replace `js:{width: getWidth()}` with `{"width": 2}` the parameter width with value 2 is sent with the request.

The documentation uses hx-vals as example for dynamically evaluated values here https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-vals/. It might be that I confuse what is executed when or something else I don't understand.

I also tried to define `getWidth` in a js file that I include and I also tried to simply us js inline and nothing worked.

Comment: your `getWidth` returns an object, but you need a value.  what happens if you `return 2` from your function?

Comment: I kept trying variation and ended up writing the wrong one down. I tried again the way I updated my post and it is still not working.

Comment: I am using htmx 1.1.0,

Comment: 1.1.0 is quite an old version. have you setup a test with the latest version? perhaps 1.1.0 did not include the currently documented functionality for `js:` ? I don't know the answer to that.

Comment: this was the issue. Thank you stranger on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the htmx version. I was using htmx 1.1.0. Updating to 1.9.5 did the trick.